# Spring override environment variable from application.properties

Tags: spring, environment-variables, properties-file

I have a spring project, which has an application.properties file, as well as an application-profile1.properties and an application-profile2.properties.

Inside application-profile1/2.properties there is one property, let's call it **my.first.property**.
The behaviour I need is the following:

In application-profile1.properties, my.first.property will have a hardcoded value, something like: `my.first.property=propertyvalue`.
In application-profile2.properties, my.first.property will try to import the value from the environment, something like: `my.first.property=${MY_FIRST_PROPERTY}`

The problem is, that it doesn't matter what I do, in my @Configuration class, when I declare a variable *myFirstPropery*, spring will always look for an environment variable that matches, and will ignore the application.properties file if it finds a match.
How can I achieve the desired behaviour? Is there a way to prevent spring from prioritising environment variables over my .properties files?

Comment: From your question i assume
for eg:
in one file (example1,properties)myFirstValue=123
in another file (example2.properties)myFirstValue=456

you want to take myFirstValue according to environment?
in development 123
and in production 234
???

Comment: Yes, I need to take the value according to environment. But for one environment, the value will be written inside the .properties file, and for the other environment the value will be read in my application.properties file from the environment variables (the ${ENV_VARIABLE_NAME} synthax)

Comment: You cannot as environment variables always override values in the `application.properties`. Also if you are using `MY_FIRST_PROPERTY` spring automatically uses that as `my.first.property` you don't need to assign it. So unless you change the name the environment variables will always take precedence. See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config (the higher in the list the higher the priority).

Comment: so there's no way to take control of this then. The only solution is to make sure the property names in my .properties files don't match those in the environment